# Old In App Purchases not retrieved Flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm testing purchases in Flutter with the [in app purchases](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin for Flutter.

I tried a purchase and completed it, but when I restart the app, the `purchasesStream` doesn't give me this past purchase, and there is no way to receive them.

Only `restorePurchases` give me those purchases again. I can't even repurchase the item, even though I refunded it. It keeps telling me I already own it.

Do I always call `restorePurchases` when the app starts? Or do I need to manually save that the user has purchased something?